# How do I ask the user for permission to send local notifications after initial launch?

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, swiftui

I would like to use local notifications in my SwiftUI app, but I need to get the user's permission first. On Apple's documentation, however, I only see information about asking permission when the app first opens.

I have a setup sequence that happens when you first open the app that guides the user through setting their preferences, one of which is notifications.

My setup so far is to have the user press "Continue" on the previous screen (NotifPermissionScreen, see below) then be taken to a blank screen where the only thing asked is notification preference. After this, I would like to load in different views depending on if they allowed notifications or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

I'm using Xcode 11 beta 3 and I'm making my app in SwiftUI.

```
struct NotifPermissionScreen : View {
    var body: some View {

        // Show notification preference message


        if (notificationsAllowed) {
            SetupScreen3()
        } else {
            SetupScreen4()
        }
    }
}
```

// NOTE: I have no idea if notificationsAllowed is a real variable, but this code represents the general structure of what I'm trying to do

Comment: Thank you so much. Would you by chance know how to modify a property of a BindableObject instance from within code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out! Here's what I did:

```
var body: some View {
    if !hasPressedNotifButton {
        Button(action: {

            // Request permission to send notifications
            self.center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound])
            { (granted, error) in

                // Hide this button by setting this @State variable to true
                self.hasPressedNotificationsButton = true

                if granted {
                    // Edit the user's data for later use
                    self.userData.wantsNotifications = true
                }
            }
        }) {
            Text("Set Notifications")
        }
        if self.userData.wantsNotifications {
            WantsNotifsView()
        } else {
            NoNotifsView()
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone needs any clarification on how this works, please let me know! :)

Comment: how do you get their device token this way though?